# How to install NetSurf web browser in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, 15.10, browser

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

> I want to install NetSurf web browser in
>   Ubuntu 14.04

This browser supports Linux(mentioned in official site of [NetSurf](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/) )
The only providing .deb binary for Debian
[image: download page of net surf browser for debian squeez]

I downloaded .deb ,from [this download link](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/downloads/gtk/),provided at official site of net surf browser.

I tried to install downloaded deb file using
**sudo dpkg -i pakagename**  method

But installation failed...

> ***What is the easy and correct way to install
>   NetSurf browser
>   in Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)***

Comment: Right-click on the .deb file and choose "Open in Software Center"? That's a generic way to install .debs that you dowload from elsewhere.

Comment: finally sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install solved the problem..
the I find out the problem some what related to gtk in Ubuntu 14.04 and net surf browser...
so finally apt-get -f install solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NetSurf** web browser is [available in the Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netsurf&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Therefore, the easiest way for users is to install from the Ubuntu repository (universe).

```
sudo apt-get install netsurf-gtk
```

In Ubuntu 14.04, NetSurf version is `2.9-2`, which is slightly newer than the Debian Squeeze binary version `2.7` provided by the official website.

Unless you prefer the latest version, which requires to download and compile the [source code from the official website](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/downloads/source/), installing from Ubuntu repository is always easier.

Answer (score 1):

Go and download [the source](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/downloads/source/) (preferably the top, most recent link on that page), and compile it yourself by extracting the archive to `~/netsurf` then:

```
cd ~/netsurf
sudo make
sudo make install
```

or simply , [download](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/downloads/gtk/)  *.deb file(binary file) from  [official website of NetSurf](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/downloads/)

and install it, by using **software centre** or by **Gdebi** package installer or 
 ***cd into directory which consists downloaded binary file and then, install it using below command***

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

here, **package_name** is downloaded package name.

***if you encounter any problems dependency problems***  ,
run,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install
```

for me,
the above command solved problem occurred during installation process.

Comment: finally sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install solved the problem..
the I find out the problem some what related to gtk in Ubuntu 14.04 and net surf browser...
so finally apt-get -f install solved my problem..so edit and add this -f install in above answer